# nginx/phpfpm is giving older php file result

Tags: linux, nginx, nfs, php-fpm

Server: ubuntu 14.04lts
nginx(v1.10) server is showing older content when i have already changed the file,the changes are seen after 3-6 minutes.
the document root directory is mounted from nfs share. the changes in the file is seen when i read/`cat` the file instantly but the same cant be seen on browser. I also tried to disable nginx sendfile off but the behaviour is random some time the change canbe seen and some time it shows older php result.

Note: i have cleared the browser cache and phpopcache is disabled 
the average latency between nfs and nginx is less than 0.3ms.
No caching server/client is done

below is my nfs mount options on client side

```
mount -t nfs
10.10.17.45:/www/public_html on /www/public_html type nfs (rw,noatime,nolock,bg,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800,addr=10.10.17.45
```

below is export conf in the nfs server

```
/www/public_html 10.10.17.40(rw,fsid=0,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

for example:- 
I have a file called `showme.php` with below content

```
<?php $var1="abc" echo $var1; ?>
```

and if i change it to

```
<?php $var1="xyz" echo $var1; ?>
```

this is not reflected on browser

Comment: corrected $var1 in question and ubuntuu/nginx versions are correct, i think i found the culprit here. In nfs mount option "actimeo=1800" in fstab,i have  set it to actimeo=1.the changes are reflected instantly <2 seconds now

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of php and what your settings are for php-fpm, this is probably an issue of PHP caching / compiling your PHP file and then refreshing it when one of the FPM processes dies off after serving the maximum number of requests.  You can always just:

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

To pick up the file change immediately.